# Addition of Bibliography in Thesis

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing my thesis in Texmaker. When I compile the main thesis file, the bibliography file is ignored. It is not shown in the Table of Contents list and also the citations are not shown in the text. Also, the references are not shown at the end.

Necessary files for a minimal example are attached. Your help to fix this problem is much appreciated!

PS: Sorry, I can't find any way to attach files. Any suggestion, please? I remember there used to be a feature, sth like upload files on this page but I can't find it this time.

Okay, the necessary files are copied in the following.

thesis.tex

```
\documentclass[twosided]{book}
\input{./Styles/preamble}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[left,modulo]{lineno}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{lettrine}  
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\input{./Styles/defs_user}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\include{./Title/title}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{5} 
\tableofcontents \cleardoublepage
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{./Chapter1/introductions} \cleardoublepage 

\backmatter
\bibliography{./Biblio/bibliothesis}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

bibliothesis.bib

```
\begin{bibliography}
@ARTICLE{Anderson67,
  AUTHOR =       {Anderson, B. D. O.},
  TITLE =        {An algebraic solution to the spectral factorization problem},
  JOURNAL =      {IEEE Transactions on Automatc Control},
  volume =       {AC-12},
  number =       {4},
  pages =        {410-414},
  YEAR =         {1967},
}
@ARTICLE{Anderson78,
  AUTHOR =       {Anderson, B. D. O.},
  TITLE =        {Second-order convergent algorithms for the steady-state {R}iccati equation},
  JOURNAL =      {International Journal of Control},
  volume =       {28},
  number =       {2},
  pages =        {295-306},
  YEAR =         {1978},
}
@ARTICLE{Tsiotras96,
  AUTHOR =       {Tsiotras, P. and M. Corless and M. Rotea},
  TITLE =        {Counter example to a recent result on the stability of nonlinear systems},
  JOURNAL =      {IMA Journal of Mathematical Control and Information}, 
  YEAR =         {1996},
  volume =       {13},
  number=        {2},
  pages =        {129-130}
}
\bibitem
@BOOK{Anderson89,
  AUTHOR =       {Anderson, B. D. O. and J. B. Moore},
  TITLE =        {Optimal Control: Linear Quadratic Methods},
  PUBLISHER =    {Prentice Hall International Inc.},
   YEAR =         {1989},
}
\bibitem
@BOOK{Do09,
  AUTHOR =       {Do, K. D. and J. Pan},
  TITLE =        {Control of Ships and Underactuated Vehicles},
  PUBLISHER =    {Springer},
   YEAR =         {2009},
}
@BOOK{Fay90,
  AUTHOR =       {Fa\"{y} , H.},
  TITLE =        {Dynamic Positioning Systems: Principles, Design and Applications},
  PUBLISHER =    {\={E}ditions Technip},
   YEAR =         {1990},
}
@CONFERENCE{Cloutier98,
  author =       {Cloutier, J. R. and C. P. Mracek and D. B. Ridgely and K. D. Hammett},
  title =        {State Dependent {R}iccati Equation Techniques: theory and applications},
  organization = {Proceedings of American Control Conference Workshop, June 24-26, 1998, Philadelphia, PA, USA.}
}
@MASTERSTHESIS{Torsetnes04,
  AUTHOR =       {Torsetnes, G.},
  TITLE =        {Nonlinear Control and Observer Design for Dynamic Positioning using Contraction Theory},
  SCHOOL =       {Norwegian University of Science and Technology, Trondheim, Norway},
  MONTH =        {January},
  YEAR =         {2004}  
}
\bibitem
@TECHREPORT{Spouge04,
   AUTHOR = {Spouge, J.},
   TITLE  = {Review of Methods for Demonstrating Redundancy in Dynamic Positioning Systems for the Offshore Industry},
   Type   = {Research Report},
   NUMBER = {15},  
   INSTITUTION = {DNV, Consulting, London},
   YEAR   = {2004}
}
\end{bibliography}
```

introduction.tex

```
\chapter{Introduction and Preliminaries}

\section{Dynamical Positioning Vessels}

The term vessel is defined as Hollow structure made to float upon the water for purposes of transportation and navigation; especially, one that is larger than a rowboat. The words vessel, ship and boat are often used interchangeably \cite{Anderson67}. Dynamic Positioning is a technique of automatically maintaining the position of a floating, unanchored vessel within a specified tolerance by using generated thrust vectors to counter the forces of wind, wave, and current forces tending to move the vessel away from the desired location \cite{Anderson78}.A Dynamic Positioning Vessel is very helpful in monitoring the natural occurrences that take place offshore and aids in vessels to maintain its position in the deep sea by pinpointing about the wind and the wave data which would otherwise make a vessel lose control and veer off its course. Through Dynamic Positioning, a vessel does not require the usage of anchors to maintain its course in the deep waters and thus can carry out its main purpose well. Vessels with dynamic positioning system are known as dynamic positioning vessels \cite{Torsetnes04}.\\
Since the development of Dynamic Positioning which incorporates the usage of SONAR \cite{Spouge04}, Radar and other comprehensive detection, vessels have started finding it easy to maintain their pace and steady their being in the deeper parts of the oceanic and sea waters \cite{Cloutier98}.

\section{Brief History}

The first vessel to fulfill the accepted definition of DP was the "Eureka", of 1961, designed and engineered by Howard Shatto[Fig. 1.1].  Drilling has been performed with winds up to 40 mph and 20 foot swells. As many as 14 core boles have been drilled in one day \cite{Fay90}.

\section{Overview Of Thesis}

In this thesis, a simple robust controller for path following of underactuated surface vessels based on hierarchical sliding-mode technique [17] is proposed. Uncertain parameters and 2-order wave disturbance are taken into consideration. \\

%\noindent \begin{large}
%\textbf{References:}
%\end{large}\\
%
%\noindent [1] Handbook Of Marine Craft Hydrodynamics And Motion Control by Thor I. Fossen, Norwegian University of Science and Technology Trondheim, Norway.\
%
%\noindent [2] Path Following And Stabilization Of Underactuated Surface Vessels Based On Adaptive Hierarchical Sliding Mode, Cheng Liu, Zao-Jian Zou and Jian-Chuan Yin, Received May 2013; revised September 2013.
```

defs_user.tex

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{des}{Description}[section]
\newtheorem{eg}{Example}[section] % This is for plain example and example will be written b/w \begin{eg}..\end{eg}.but if you need a triangle to mark the end of the example then add the next line in the preamble and example will be written b/w \begin{example} ... \end{example}.
\newenvironment{example}{\begin{eg}}{\hfill $\blacktriangle$ \end{eg}}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\newcommand{\ol}[1]{%
\mbox{$\overline{#1}$}}

% My additions start

\usepackage{bm,amsbsy} 

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section] %[theorem] it should be b/w {.} and {.}
% \newtheorem{remark}{Remark} % [remark] should be b/w {rmk} and {Remark}. [section] represents sectionwise numberingandcomeslast 
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section] % [proposition]
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]{\bf}{\rm}
\usepackage{graphicx,color} % This and the following statements are to support the inclusion of block diagram with latex text 
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.pdftex}{pdf}{*}{}

\newtheorem{Corol}{Corollary}[section] % to support corollary 18-05-10
\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\bgingroup

\newenvironment{acknow}{%
\renewcommand*{\abstractname}{Acknowledgments} \abstract}{%
\endabstract}
\newcommand{\st}[0]{\superscript{st}}
\newcommand{\nd}[0]{\superscript{nd}}
\newcommand{\rd}[0]{\superscript{rd}}

% My additions end

\newcommand{\fra}[2]{\displaystyle\frac{\mathstrut#1}{\mathstrut#2}}
\def\ZZ{{\mathchoice {\hbox{$\sf\textstyle Z\kern-0.4em Z$}}
{\hbox{$\sf\textstyle Z\kern-0.4em Z$}}
{\hbox{$\sf\scriptstyle Z\kern-0.3em Z$}}
{\hbox{$\sf\scriptscriptstyle Z\kern-0.2em Z$}}}}

\newcommand{\tabfrac}[2]{%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
    \fbox{$\frac{#1}{#2}$}%
}

\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}

\def\bsb{\boldsymbol{b}}
\def\bsA{\boldsymbol{A}}
\def\bsB{\boldsymbol{B}}
\def\bsr{\boldsymbol{r}}
\def\bse{\boldsymbol{e}}
\def\bsf{\boldsymbol{f}}
\def\bsc{\boldsymbol{c}}
\def\bsu{\boldsymbol{u}}
\def\bsv{\boldsymbol{v}}
\def\bsC{\boldsymbol{C}}
\def\bsD{\boldsymbol{D}}
\def\bsL{\boldsymbol{L}}
\def\bsH{\boldsymbol{H}}
\def\bsG{\boldsymbol{G}}
\def\bsK{\boldsymbol{K}}
\def\bsN{\boldsymbol{N}}
\def\bsw{\boldsymbol{w}}
\def\bsX{\boldsymbol{X}}
\def\bsx{\boldsymbol{x}}
\def\bss{\boldsymbol{s}}
\def\bsh{\boldsymbol{h}}
\def\bsj{\boldsymbol{j}}
\def\bsl{\boldsymbol{l}}
\def\bsT{\boldsymbol{T}}
\def\bsR{\boldsymbol{R}}
\def\bsP{\boldsymbol{P}}
\def\bsJ{\boldsymbol{J}}
\def\sst{\scriptscriptstyle}
\def\sct{\scriptstyle}
\def\bbbr{{\rm I\!R}}
\def\bsF{\boldsymbol{F}}
\def\bstheta{\boldsymbol{\theta}}
\def\bsalpha{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}
\def\bskappa{\boldsymbol{\kappa}}
\def\wtL{\widetilde{L}}
\def\wtR{\widetilde{R}}
\def\wtP{\widetilde{P}}
\def\wtS{\widetilde{S}}
\def\wtQ{\widetilde{Q}}
\def\wtD{\widetilde{D}}
\def\wtG{\widetilde{G}}
\def\wtC{\widetilde{C}}
\def\wtM{\widetilde{M}}
\def\wta{\widetilde{a}}
\def\wtu{\widetilde{u}}
\def\wtv{\widetilde{v}}
\def\wtx{\widetilde{x}}
\def\wty{\widetilde{y}}
```

preamble.tex

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}      % AMS Math
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                    % Fancy Header and Footer % blindtext is my addition
\usepackage{pstricks}                    % Specific postscript extras
\usepackage{./Styles/cases}                       % Special cases construct
%\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}       % More control on appendices (My addition is titletoc)
\usepackage{epsfig}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}}
% \usepackage{drftcite}                    % Citation labels instead of numbers
% \usepackage{./styles/refcheck}                    % Print labels
\usepackage{layout}                      % Prints an overview of all the margins 
%                                          % on the page when you add \layout to 
                                         % your texfile
% Hyphenation
%
\hyphenation{hy-phe-na-tion}
\usepackage[Lenny]{./Styles/fncychap}

\usepackage[american,dutch]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
% \usepackage[dutch]{babel}
% commenting next package changes font of calligraphic math (at least)!
% \usepackage{mathptmx} % Important package, don't uncomment
% \usepackage{charter}
% \usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Layout definition for Shah's thesis
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[
paperheight=240mm,
paperwidth=170mm,
textheight=200mm,
textwidth=120mm,
top=20mm,
bottom=20mm,
outer=20mm,
% headsep=8mm
]{geometry}

% move from center
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}
%\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5cm} 

\linespread{1.03} % to allow for nicer line distance

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Heading commands for Shah's thesis
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% define the headings %%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}                              % delete current setting for header and footer
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{         % Lower Case Chapter marker style
  \markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} %\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} (old line, changed today 12-11-10)
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{         % Lower case Section marker style
  \markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    % Page number (boldface) in left on even
%\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \rightmark}}
%\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  HyperReference
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \RequirePackage[dvips,ps2pdf,pdfpagelabels,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[pdfpagelabels,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
% \RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,
            breaklinks=true,
            citecolor=black,
            urlcolor=black,
            linkcolor=black,
            menucolor=darkblue,
            anchorcolor=red,
            pagecolor=cyan,
            }

\usepackage{./Styles/breakurl}
\urlstyle{same}

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother \clearpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}
```

title.tex

```
% define relative path to images for this .tex file
\graphicspath{{./Logo_images/}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define below the title of your thesis, the subtitle, and your own name

\newcommand{\thetitle}{YOur Title} 
%\newcommand{\thetitleconnector}{based on}
\newcommand{\thesubtitle}{Your Subtitle} 
\newcommand{\theauthor}{Your Name}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{30mm}

\begin{center}
     \textbf{\huge \thetitle}\\[\baselineskip]\textbf{\LARGE \thesubtitle}%\\[\baselineskip]\textbf{\Large \thetitleconnector}
\end{center}

\vspace{30mm}

\smallskip{}


\vspace{1cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% and on page 4 an overview of your review committee
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage %
\thispagestyle{empty}

\bigskip{}

\noindent

\vspace*{\fill}
\selectlanguage{american} %american replaced with english to support \blindtext but later aborted it. 

% possibly include your logos and make acknowledgements to funding


\vspace*{\fill}

\bigskip{}

\bigskip{}
\noindent All rights reserved. No part of the material protected by
this copyright notice may be reproduced or utilized in any form or
by any means, electronic or mechanical, including photocopying,
recording or by any information storage and retrieval system, without
written permission of the author.

\bigskip{}
```

Shah

Comment: Welcome the TeX.SE! Did you remember to run BibTeX? Incidentally, there is no wagon this site to *attach* files. However, it's straightforward to copy and paste the contents of text files.

Comment: Please make a MWE (minimal) working example (it is unlikely that we need you entire thesis to sort out the problem).

Comment: Thanks for posting some actual code. You haven't answered my earlier question, though: Did you actually run BibTeX (and then run LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes)? If you did run BibTeX, did you get any error messages? (Hint: The instructions `\begin{bibliography}` and `\end{bibliography}` will almost certainly cause a fatal crash. Remove them and see what happens.) If you have not yet run BibTeX, what happens if you do?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the following things:

- Remove the instructions `\begin{bibliography}` and `\end{bibliography}` as well as the three instances of `\bibitem` from the file `bibliothesis.bib`. A bib file should consist only of bibliographic entries, certainly no LaTeX code.
- After a successful LaTeX run, be sure to run BibTeX and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

Here's a screenshot of the resulting Bibliography page. Successive `filecontents` environments are used to created a self-contained file. (Incidentally, I had to comment out some parts of your code that were throwing errors before your code would actually compile.)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliothesis.bib}
@ARTICLE{Anderson67,
  AUTHOR =       {Anderson, B. D. O.},
  TITLE =        {An algebraic solution to the spectral factorization problem},
  JOURNAL =      {IEEE Transactions on Automatc Control},
  volume =       {AC-12},
  number =       {4},
  pages =        {410-414},
  YEAR =         {1967},
}
@ARTICLE{Anderson78,
  AUTHOR =       {Anderson, B. D. O.},
  TITLE =        {Second-order convergent algorithms for the steady-state {R}iccati equation},
  JOURNAL =      {International Journal of Control},
  volume =       {28},
  number =       {2},
  pages =        {295-306},
  YEAR =         {1978},
}
@ARTICLE{Tsiotras96,
  AUTHOR =       {Tsiotras, P. and M. Corless and M. Rotea},
  TITLE =        {Counter example to a recent result on the stability of nonlinear systems},
  JOURNAL =      {IMA Journal of Mathematical Control and Information}, 
  YEAR =         {1996},
  volume =       {13},
  number=        {2},
  pages =        {129-130}
}

@BOOK{Anderson89,
  AUTHOR =       {Anderson, B. D. O. and J. B. Moore},
  TITLE =        {Optimal Control: Linear Quadratic Methods},
  PUBLISHER =    {Prentice Hall International Inc.},
   YEAR =         {1989},
}

@BOOK{Do09,
  AUTHOR =       {Do, K. D. and J. Pan},
  TITLE =        {Control of Ships and Underactuated Vehicles},
  PUBLISHER =    {Springer},
   YEAR =         {2009},
}
@BOOK{Fay90,
  AUTHOR =       {Fa{\"y} , H.},
  TITLE =        {Dynamic Positioning Systems: Principles, Design and Applications},
  PUBLISHER =    {\={E}ditions Technip},
   YEAR =         {1990},
}
@CONFERENCE{Cloutier98,
  author =       {Cloutier, J. R. and C. P. Mracek and D. B. Ridgely and K. D. Hammett},
  title =        {State Dependent {R}iccati Equation Techniques: theory and applications},
  organization = {Proceedings of American Control Conference Workshop, June 24--26, 1998, Philadelphia, PA, USA.}
}
@MASTERSTHESIS{Torsetnes04,
  AUTHOR =       {Torsetnes, G.},
  TITLE =        {Nonlinear Control and Observer Design for Dynamic Positioning using Contraction Theory},
  SCHOOL =       {Norwegian University of Science and Technology, Trondheim, Norway},
  MONTH =        {January},
  YEAR =         {2004}  
}

@TECHREPORT{Spouge04,
   AUTHOR = {Spouge, J.},
   TITLE  = {Review of Methods for Demonstrating Redundancy in Dynamic Positioning Systems for the Offshore Industry},
   Type   = {Research Report},
   NUMBER = {15},  
   INSTITUTION = {DNV, Consulting, London},
   YEAR   = {2004}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{introduction.tex}
\chapter{Introduction and Preliminaries}

\section{Dynamical Positioning Vessels}

The term vessel is defined as Hollow structure made to float upon the water for purposes of transportation and navigation; especially, one that is larger than a rowboat. The words vessel, ship and boat are often used interchangeably \cite{Anderson67}. Dynamic Positioning is a technique of automatically maintaining the position of a floating, unanchored vessel within a specified tolerance by using generated thrust vectors to counter the forces of wind, wave, and current forces tending to move the vessel away from the desired location \cite{Anderson78}. A Dynamic Positioning Vessel is very helpful in monitoring the natural occurrences that take place offshore and aids in vessels to maintain its position in the deep sea by pinpointing about the wind and the wave data which would otherwise make a vessel lose control and veer off its course. Through Dynamic Positioning, a vessel does not require the usage of anchors to maintain its course in the deep waters and thus can carry out its main purpose well. Vessels with dynamic positioning system are known as dynamic positioning vessels \cite{Torsetnes04}.

Since the development of Dynamic Positioning which incorporates the usage of SONAR \cite{Spouge04}, Radar and other comprehensive detection, vessels have started finding it easy to maintain their pace and steady their being in the deeper parts of the oceanic and sea waters \cite{Cloutier98}.

\section{Brief History}

The first vessel to fulfill the accepted definition of DP was the ``Eureka'', of 1961, designed and engineered by Howard Shatto[Fig. 1.1].  Drilling has been performed with winds up to 40 mph and 20 foot swells. As many as 14 core boles have been drilled in one day \cite{Fay90}.

\section{Overview Of Thesis}

In this thesis, a simple robust controller for path following of underactuated surface vessels based on hierarchical sliding-mode technique [17] is proposed. Uncertain parameters and 2-order wave disturbance are taken into consideration.

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{defs_user.tex}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{des}{Description}[section]
\newtheorem{eg}{Example}[section] % This is for plain example and example will be written b/w \begin{eg}..\end{eg}.but if you need a triangle to mark the end of the example then add the next line in the preamble and example will be written b/w \begin{example} ... \end{example}.
\newenvironment{example}{\begin{eg}}{\hfill $\blacktriangle$ \end{eg}}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\newcommand{\ol}[1]{%
\mbox{$\overline{#1}$}}

% My additions start

\usepackage{bm,amsbsy} 

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section] %[theorem] it should be b/w {.} and {.}
% \newtheorem{remark}{Remark} % [remark] should be b/w {rmk} and {Remark}. [section] represents sectionwise numberingandcomeslast 
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section] % [proposition]
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]{\bf}{\rm}
\usepackage{graphicx,color} % This and the following statements are to support the inclusion of block diagram with latex text 
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.pdftex}{pdf}{*}{}

\newtheorem{Corol}{Corollary}[section] % to support corollary 18-05-10
%\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup

\newenvironment{acknow}{%
\renewcommand*{\abstractname}{Acknowledgments} \abstract}{\endabstract}
\newcommand{\st}[0]{\superscript{st}}
\newcommand{\nd}[0]{\superscript{nd}}
\newcommand{\rd}[0]{\superscript{rd}}

% My additions end

\newcommand{\fra}[2]{\displaystyle\frac{\mathstrut#1}{\mathstrut#2}}
\def\ZZ{{\mathchoice {\hbox{$\sf\textstyle Z\kern-0.4em Z$}}
{\hbox{$\sf\textstyle Z\kern-0.4em Z$}}
{\hbox{$\sf\scriptstyle Z\kern-0.3em Z$}}
{\hbox{$\sf\scriptscriptstyle Z\kern-0.2em Z$}}}}

\newcommand{\tabfrac}[2]{%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
    \fbox{$\frac{#1}{#2}$}%
}

\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}

\def\bsb{\boldsymbol{b}}
\def\bsA{\boldsymbol{A}}
\def\bsB{\boldsymbol{B}}
\def\bsr{\boldsymbol{r}}
\def\bse{\boldsymbol{e}}
\def\bsf{\boldsymbol{f}}
\def\bsc{\boldsymbol{c}}
\def\bsu{\boldsymbol{u}}
\def\bsv{\boldsymbol{v}}
\def\bsC{\boldsymbol{C}}
\def\bsD{\boldsymbol{D}}
\def\bsL{\boldsymbol{L}}
\def\bsH{\boldsymbol{H}}
\def\bsG{\boldsymbol{G}}
\def\bsK{\boldsymbol{K}}
\def\bsN{\boldsymbol{N}}
\def\bsw{\boldsymbol{w}}
\def\bsX{\boldsymbol{X}}
\def\bsx{\boldsymbol{x}}
\def\bss{\boldsymbol{s}}
\def\bsh{\boldsymbol{h}}
\def\bsj{\boldsymbol{j}}
\def\bsl{\boldsymbol{l}}
\def\bsT{\boldsymbol{T}}
\def\bsR{\boldsymbol{R}}
\def\bsP{\boldsymbol{P}}
\def\bsJ{\boldsymbol{J}}
\def\sst{\scriptscriptstyle}
\def\sct{\scriptstyle}
\def\bbbr{{\rm I\!R}}
\def\bsF{\boldsymbol{F}}
\def\bstheta{\boldsymbol{\theta}}
\def\bsalpha{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}
\def\bskappa{\boldsymbol{\kappa}}
\def\wtL{\widetilde{L}}
\def\wtR{\widetilde{R}}
\def\wtP{\widetilde{P}}
\def\wtS{\widetilde{S}}
\def\wtQ{\widetilde{Q}}
\def\wtD{\widetilde{D}}
\def\wtG{\widetilde{G}}
\def\wtC{\widetilde{C}}
\def\wtM{\widetilde{M}}
\def\wta{\widetilde{a}}
\def\wtu{\widetilde{u}}
\def\wtv{\widetilde{v}}
\def\wtx{\widetilde{x}}
\def\wty{\widetilde{y}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{preamble.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}      % AMS Math
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                    % Fancy Header and Footer % blindtext is my addition
\usepackage{pstricks}                    % Specific postscript extras
\usepackage{cases}                       % Special cases construct
%\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}       % More control on appendices (My addition is titletoc)
\usepackage{epsfig}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}}
% \usepackage{drftcite}                    % Citation labels instead of numbers
% \usepackage{refcheck}                    % Print labels
\usepackage{layout}                      % Prints an overview of all the margins 
%                                          % on the page when you add \layout to 
                                         % your texfile
% Hyphenation
%
\hyphenation{hy-phe-na-tion}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\usepackage[american,dutch]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
% \usepackage[dutch]{babel}
% commenting next package changes font of calligraphic math (at least)!
% \usepackage{mathptmx} % Important package, don't uncomment
% \usepackage{charter}
% \usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}  % 'txfonts' package is obsolete
%\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Layout definition for Shah's thesis
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[
paperheight=240mm,
paperwidth=170mm,
textheight=200mm,
textwidth=120mm,
top=20mm,
bottom=20mm,
outer=20mm,
% headsep=8mm
]{geometry}

% move from center
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}
%\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5cm} 

%\linespread{1.03} % to allow for nicer line distance
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.03}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Heading commands for Shah's thesis
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% define the headings %%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}                              % delete current setting for header and footer
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{         % Lower Case Chapter marker style
  \markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} %\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} (old line, changed today 12-11-10)
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{         % Lower case Section marker style
  \markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    % Page number (boldface) in left on even
%\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \rightmark}}
%\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  HyperReference
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \RequirePackage[dvips,ps2pdf,pdfpagelabels,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[pdfpagelabels,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
% \RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,
            breaklinks=true,
            citecolor=black,
            urlcolor=black,
            linkcolor=black,
            menucolor=darkblue,
            anchorcolor=red,
            pagecolor=cyan,
            }

\usepackage{breakurl}
\urlstyle{same}

%\makeatletter
%\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
%    \hbox{}
%    \thispagestyle{plain}
%    \newpage
%    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
%\makeatother 
%\clearpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{title.tex}
% define relative path to images for this .tex file
\graphicspath{{./Logo_images/}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define below the title of your thesis, the subtitle, and your own name

\newcommand{\thetitle}{YOur Title} 
%\newcommand{\thetitleconnector}{based on}
\newcommand{\thesubtitle}{Your Subtitle} 
\newcommand{\theauthor}{Your Name}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{30mm}

\begin{center}
     \textbf{\huge \thetitle}\\[\baselineskip]\textbf{\LARGE \thesubtitle}%\\[\baselineskip]\textbf{\Large \thetitleconnector}
\end{center}

\vspace{30mm}

\smallskip{}


\vspace{1cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% and on page 4 an overview of your review committee
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage %
\thispagestyle{empty}

\bigskip{}

\noindent

\vspace*{\fill}
\selectlanguage{american} %american replaced with english to support \blindtext but later aborted it. 

% possibly include your logos and make acknowledgements to funding


\vspace*{\fill}

\bigskip{}

\bigskip{}
\noindent All rights reserved. No part of the material protected by
this copyright notice may be reproduced or utilized in any form or
by any means, electronic or mechanical, including photocopying,
recording or by any information storage and retrieval system, without
written permission of the author.

\bigskip{}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[twosided]{book}
\input{preamble}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[left,modulo]{lineno}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{lettrine}  
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\input{defs_user}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\include{title}
%\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{5} 
\tableofcontents 
\cleardoublepage
\mainmatter
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{introduction} 
%\cleardoublepage 

\backmatter
\bibliography{bibliothesis}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico! I have commented the \begin{bibliography} and \end{bibliography} items and the 3 \bibitem entries in bibliothesis file. I ran the thesis.tex file afterwards several times but the problem remains as such. I don't get your sentence about running the BibteX file. Where this will should be located and how to run it? Is it located in Biblio folder in my settings?

Comment: @user69995 - Please consult the user guide of the TeXmaker program to figure out how to invoke BibTeX. (I don't use TeXmaker, so I'm afraid I can't help you in this regard.) Basically, if your main tex file -- the one that contains the `\documentclass` instruction -- is named `main.tex`, the compilation sequence is `latex main`, `bibtex main`, `latex main`, and once more `latex main`. Notice: no file extensions should be written out. It takes four steps to fully propate all changes. One doesn't "run" BibTeX on the bib file -- one runs it on the `main` file.